Is there a collection of tutorials that focus on minimalism?
There is an endless amount of frameworks, libraries and models now with a corresponding amount of tutorials. But most of them are quite verbose and somewhat unfocused. Is there any collection of tutorials that try to achieve something simple with as few lines as possible? My canonical example would be trying to verify that a new installation of a framework/library works at all. It could be as simple as ./trendy_framework_run_benchmark.py. When trying to verify that my new onnxruntime-installation works, i couldn't find anything of the sort.
I'm not afraid to work through more elaborate tutorials, but I would like to be able to point other people towards tutorials with clearly defined prerequisites that can be tried in <1 minute and result in a small, but quick success (or failure).
As another example, outside of AI it would be easy to give 1-liner-tutorials for simple tasks: verify that the DNS query tool dig is installed and in your PATH via which dig. Check that dig works via dig google.com. And so on.

Are you looking for tutorials or scripts? From your question, it seems that you're looking for scripts or commands to do stuff.

Both. Anything that can be a solution to a simple problem.
